# Using MockRoundtrip in Stripes with Guice

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice, stripes

I've recently introduced Guice into my ActionBeans, where previously the actionbean had its data access layer implementation hardcoded.

I have an integration test like this:

```
MockServletContext context = TestHelper.getServletContext();
MockRoundtrip trip = new MockRoundtrip(context, LoginActionBean.class);


trip.setParameter("authenticate", "Login");
trip.setParameter("username", "testuser2");
trip.setParameter("password", "testuser2pass");
trip.setParameter("targetUrl", "Activity.action?jobId=1");
trip.execute();

LoginActionBean bean = trip.getActionBean(LoginActionBean.class);
```

Now that I'm using Guice, I can't find a way to inject the dependencies into the LoginActionBean, since I never actually instantiate it myself.

How can I tell guice to inject the dependencies into this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure the [MockServletContext](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/mock/MockServletContext.html) with a Guice configuration, like you have in your web.xml (probably in your *TestHelper* class *getServletContext()* method).